# how to Decrypt Application settings before binding?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I am using Application settings in my c# project to save gmail username and password. Before saving the settings I am encrypting the plain text password.   When I am restarting the app retrieving them is of course without any problem but the retrieved password is encrypted.  What I want is to decrypt it back before binding back to the textbox 
The code generated by the designer is something like the follows:

```
this.tb_Gmail_Password.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", global::MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default, "GmailPassword", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

I don’t know if I am able to put my question properly. Plz feel free to kick me if I sound like speaking alien language. I will give more description as per your suggestion…

Regards,
N10i.

--edit--

while saving the configuration i am using a custom function to encrypt the password i.e.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.GmailPassword = MyApp.EncPass(tb_Gmail_Password.Text);
```

can i use something similar like

```
this.tb_Gmail_Password.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", global::MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default, MyApp.DecPass("GmailPassword"), true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

i.e.

```
MyApp.DecPass("GmailPassword")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encrypt the configuration using DPAPI [DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.dpapiprotectedconfigurationprovider(VS.80).aspx), and you decrypt it using the same at application start up, see [Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: thanks for your reply i will look into DPAPI but is it possible to use something similar as i have mentioned in the edited post?

thanks and regards,
N10I

Comment: You can attach a delegate to the Setting.Default.OnSettingsLoaded and to Settings.Default.OnSettingsSaving to decrypt/encrypt your password on the fly, as is being loaded from/saved to the config file.

Comment: can u plz. explain using a sample code. if will be a great help if u can!